# Reuse of shared ViewModel instance between fragments, main activity and navigation menu to display different informations

Tags: android, mvvm, navigation, fragment, android-viewmodel

I'm developing my application following the Single Activity Main Fragments approach. I have two fragments, `ShowProfileFragment` and `EditProfileFragment`, that both shares a `ProfileViewModel` to display the user informations and edit them. `EditProfileFragment` can only be accessed via `ShowProfileFragment`. `ShowProfileFragment` is accessible from the navigatio menu.

I also have a navigation menu which displays the name and the email of the user, it retrieves those informations via databinding observing the corresponding fields in the `ProfileViewModel`. Assuming that the user is already authenticated, the `ProfileViewModel` is being created into the `MainActivity` so that I can correctly see the user informations from the navigation menu at the application startup.

Until now my application has the following structure:

```
MainActivity (A)      uses ProfileViewModel

ShowProfileFragment   uses ProfileViewModel
  |-> EditProfileFragment   uses ProfileViewModel

NavigationDrawer      uses ProfileViewModel
```

Let's say I have a list of users (RecyclerView) in a `UserListFragment`. Now the application structure would be like this:

```
MainActivity (A)           uses ProfileViewModel

ShowProfileFragment        uses ProfileViewModel
  |-> EditProfileFragment  uses ProfileViewModel
UserListFragment           

NavigationDrawer           uses ProfileViewModel
```

The problem is that, I need to reuse the `ShowProfileFragment` to display the current selected user details. So far, I instantiated an instance of the `ProfileViewModel` that has the same lifecycle of the `MainActivity` so that I can correctly display the authenticated user information from the navigation menu.

My idea is to use the `ProfileViewModel` only for the `ShowProfileFragment` (and `EditProfileFragment`) and `UserListFragment` so that when I access the `ShowProfileFragment` from the navigation menu I pass as an argument a boolean that says the navigation started from the navigation menu, showing the full user details and enabling the navigation to the `EditProfileFragment`. When the `ShowProfileFragment` is accessed from the user list, the `ShowProfileFragment` will display less informations and disable the `EditProfileFragment` navigation path. The user details in the navigation menu will be managed using different code without involving the `ProfileViewModel`.

I really don't know if it is a good solution as I'm relatively new to Android development. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better solution?